# kafka broker config change dynamically

Tags: apache-zookeeper, apache-kafka

I'm using kafka_2.9.2-0.8.1.1 with zookeeper 3.4.6.

Is there a way to change broker configuration settings dynamically? Specifically, I want to change `controlled.shutdown.enable`

`bin/kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zookeeper01.mysite.com --config controlled.shutdown.enable=true --alter`

but I get the error

`Missing required argument "[topic]"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you can't change broker configs dynamically.

There are two kinds of configurations related to the brokers: [broker configs](http://kafka.apache.org/081/documentation.html#brokerconfigs) and [per-topic configs](http://kafka.apache.org/081/documentation.html#topic-config).

Since per-topic configs are managed by a Zookeeper cluster, you can change those with `kafka-topics.sh` on the fly.

`controlled.shutdown.enable` is, however, a **broker config** which can be only set up by server.properties file and requires broker restarting when to be changed.

This issue was also discussed in Kafka JIRA:
[[KAFKA-1229] Reload broker config without a restart](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-1229)

Comment: Thanks. I thought I overlooked some tool.

Answer (score 2):

You can now from 1.1 onwards: [Dynamic Broker Config](http://kafka.apache.org/11/documentation.html#dynamicbrokerconfigs)

In your case, something like:

```
> bin/kafka-configs.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 \ 
--entity-type brokers --entity-name 0 --alter \ 
--add-config controlled.shutdown.enable=true
```